# What is the equivalent of django.db.models.loading.get_model() in Django 1.9?

Tags: django

I want to use `get_model()` to avoid cyclic imports in my models, but I get `name 'get_model' is not defined` error. I read that `get_model()` was depreciated in 1.8 and apparently is not present in 1.9. What is the equivalent call? Or is there another way to avoid cyclic imports in two `models.py` files?

Comment: `apps.get_model()` will not help you resolve circular imports. If you avoid circular imports by using `apps.get_model()` within a function, an inline import will work just as fine. For `ForeignKey` and the like, you can use string references, i.e. `models.ForeignKey('myapp.MyModel')`.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`django.db.models.loading.get_model()` has been removed in django 1.9.

You are supposed to use `django.apps` instead.

```
>>> from django.apps import apps
>>> apps.get_model('shop', 'Product')
<class 'shop.models.Product'>
>>>
```

[Django docs reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model)

Comment: This was really helpful in my converting an app to go from Django 1.8 to Django 1.11 compatibility. What is the difference between `django.apps.apps.get_model` and `django.apps.AppConfig.get_model`?

Comment: `apps.get_model` is useful in global context (models of all apps) and `AppConfig.get_model` is useful for finding models for a specific app.

Comment: @v1k45 - does this add overhead? If I `get_model('someapp.Model2`)` inside a `@classmethod` of `Model1`, will I see a speed decrease? (as opposed to importing once at the top of the file in another module) I'm calling said `classmethod` thousands of times an hour..

Comment: @zerohedge The `get_model` method imports a python class using string, similar things are done throughout django. You won't see a speed issue due to this. Even if you called it few hundred thousand times a second.

PS: If you can import the model, you should do that instead. `get_model` is intended to be used for dynamically importing or lazyloading models.