# How can import different models according to url arguments

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I am writing a website that requires importing different sql models to different urls according to argument. Specifically:

if the url is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/abc
```

where abc is the also a model name in sql database

then in views.py:

```
def detail(request, arg):
  from book.models import arg
```

my expected result is:

```
  from book.models import abc
```

any idea? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can dynamically import like this :

```
request = "test.com/t/winsound"
importValue = request.rsplit("/",1)[1]
exec("import "+importValue)
winsound.Beep(600,600)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I try to embed that in the code, but it results in ImportError Exception Value: cannot import name 'abc'.

Comment: Actually, I search a bit and found that something like get_models application can help, but cannot figure out how to use it in Django 1.10.4. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

In your case:

```
def detail(request, arg):
    import books.models as books_models
    function = getattr(books_models, arg)
```

Another way of doing it is like this:

`function = getattr(__import__('books.models'), arg)`

Comment: I think this will be helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075190/what-is-getattr-exactly-and-how-do-i-use-it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the inputs. While your answers should be valid, I also figure out a way to it as below:

```
from django.apps import apps

def detail(request, arg):
    db_arg = apps.get_model('book', arg)
```

then the abc database will be assigned to db_arg

I think this question is duplicate to this one:
[What is the equivalent of django.db.models.loading.get_model() in Django 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234635/what-is-the-equivalent-of-django-db-models-loading-get-model-in-django-1-9)